# how to convert .ckpt file to .pb

Tags: tensorflow, solid-state-drive

I use ssd_mobilenets in Object detection API to train my own model, and get .ckpt files. It works well on my computer, but now I want to use the model on my phone. So, I need convert it to .pb file. I do not know how to do it, can any one help? By the way, the graph of ssd_mobilenets is complex, I can not find which is the output of model. Is there any one knowing the name of the output?

Answer (score 2):

Use [export_inference_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py) to convert model checkpoint file into a .pb file.

```
python tensorflow_models/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py \
--input_type image_tensor \
--pipeline_config_path architecture_used_while_training.config \
--trained path_to_saved_ckpt/model.ckpt-NUMBER \
--output_directory model/
```

Comment: I created a `.ckpt` file using `tf.train.Saver()`, but it didn't give me a `.config` file. Where does that come from?

Comment: Use the same config file that you used to train the model or take one from sample configs given by TF

Answer (score 0):

- This is the 4th code cell in object_detection_tutorial.ipynb in this link -https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb

  ```
  # What model to download.
  MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
  MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
  DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'

  # Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
  PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

  # List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
  PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')

  NUM_CLASSES = 90
  ```
- Now the cell clearly says the `.pb` filename which is `/frozen_inference_graph.pb`
- So you already have the `.pb` file why do you want to convert ??
- Anyways you can refer thsi link for freezing the graph: https://github.com/jayshah19949596/Tensorboard-Visualization-Freezing-Graph
- you need to use `tensorflow.python.tools.freeze_graph()` function to convert your `.ckpt` file to `.pb` file
- The below code line shows how you do it

  ```
  freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph_path,
                            input_saver_def_path,
                            input_binary,
                            input_checkpoint_path,
                            output_node_names,
                            restore_op_name,
                            filename_tensor_name,
                            output_graph_path,
                            clear_devices,
                            initializer_nodes)
  ```

  - input_graph_path : is the path to `.pb` file where you will write your graph and this `.pb` file is not frozen. you will use `tf.train.write_graph()` to write the graph
  - input_saver_def_path : you can keep it an empty string
  - input_binary : it is a boolean value keep it false so that the file genertaed is not binary and human readable
  - input_checkpoint_path : path to the `.ckpt file`
  - output_graph_path : path where you want to write you `pb` file
  - clear_devices : boolean value ... keep it False
  - output_node_names : explicit tensor node names that you want to save
  - restore_op_name : string value that should be "save/restore_all"
  - filename_tensor_name = "save/Const:0"
  - initializer_nodes = ""

Comment: I don't understand `freeze_graph`. You're saying it converts a `.ckpt` file to a `.pb` file, but `input_graph_path` is a path to a pre-existing `.pb` file? Where does that come from?